# Is there any way to solve this json decode error?

Tags: python, json

I'm Trying to translate a Telugu string into English using py_translator module but getting this following error at 2nd line of code.

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
from py_translator import Translator
```

## error at line below

```
s = Translator().translate(text='కాంగ్రెస్, బిజెపిలతో ఢీ: మరోసారి కేసీఆర్ ఫెడరల్ ఫ్రంట్ మాట', dest='en').text

print(s)
```

Comment: "Languages:
Deutsch | English | Spanish | French | Italian | Russian" only ?

Comment: @Mika72 That is for the documentation page. The module states "Supports translation from any language". As it uses google api as a backend, I suppose the expected result is indeed "Congress and BJP: Once again KCR is the Federal Front"

Comment: I do not reproduce your problem. This could be a version-specific issue. I'm using py-translator-2.1.9 under python 3.7. It could also help if you pasted the full traceback to locate more precisely the issue (not just the JSONDecodeError).

Comment: Same here. Python 3.7.2 and py-translator 2.1.9 and it works.

Comment: Works for me as well Python 3.6.6 and py_translator 2.1.9

Comment: i'm using the same version but still getting this error.